# Angular 9 with Tailwind CSS, PostCSS, SCSS and MiniCssExtractPlugin not compiling

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, tailwind-css, angular-devkit

I have been trying to use Tailwind CSS in my Angular 9 project. I am able to get it to work fine if I follow this guide:
https://dev.to/seankerwin/angular-8-tailwind-css-guide-3m45

The problem arises when I try to use MiniCssExtractPlugin to separate out my CSS into another file. I get the following webpack error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:159:23
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1409:36
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:182:20
    at context.callback (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:159:14
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1414:32
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at normalizeBackSlashDirection (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:16:17)
    at new RequestShortener (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\RequestShortener.js:26:15)
    at new Compiler (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:195:27)
    at Compiler.createChildCompiler (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:558:25)
    at Compilation.createChildCompiler (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2243:24)
    at Object.pitch (F:\Workspace\portfolio-y2k20\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:89:43)
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 2 } },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                            plugins: () => [
                                require('postcss-import'),
                                require('tailwindcss'),
                                require('autoprefixer'),
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].css',
        }),
    ],
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
    {
        "name": "portfolio-y2k20",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng s -o",
            "start:prod": "ng s -o -c=production",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e"
        },
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
            "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
            "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0",
            "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
            "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
            "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
            "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
            "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
            "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0",
            "tslib": "^1.10.0",
            "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.0",
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
            "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
            "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
            "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
            "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
            "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.6.2",
            "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
            "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
            "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
            "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
            "karma": "~4.3.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
            "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
            "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
            "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
            "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
            "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
            "prettier": "^2.0.5",
            "protractor": "~5.4.3",
            "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
            "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
            "tslint": "~5.18.0",
            "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
            "typescript": "~3.7.5"
        }
    }
```

My `angular.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "portfolio-y2k20": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "ag",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "customWebpackConfig": {
                            "path": "./webpack.config.js"
                        },
                        "outputPath": "dist/portfolio-y2k20",
                        "baseHref": "/portfolio-y2k20/",
                        "deployUrl": "/portfolio-y2k20/",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "extractCss": true,
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles/styles.scss",
                            "node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "customWebpackConfig": {
                            "path": "./webpack.config.js"
                        },
                        "browserTarget": "portfolio-y2k20:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "portfolio-y2k20:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "portfolio-y2k20:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles/styles.scss",
                            "node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "portfolio-y2k20:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "portfolio-y2k20:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "deploy": {
                    "builder": "angular-cli-ghpages:deploy",
                    "options": {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "portfolio-y2k20"
}
```

Here's also my `tailwind.config.js`, if it matters:

```js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            screens: {
                xxl: '1440px',
                fullHD: '1920px',
                '4k': '2560px',
            },
        },
        textColor: {
            primary: 'var(--color-text-primary)',
            secondary: 'var(--color-text-secondary)',
            'app-primary': 'var(--color-primary)',
            'app-secondary': 'var(--color-secondary)',
            navbar: 'var(--color-text-navbar)',
        },
        backgroundColor: {
            primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
            secondary: 'var(--color-secondary)',
            'app-primary': 'var(--color-bg-primary)',
            'app-secondary': 'var(--color-bg-secondary)',
            navbar: 'var(--color-bg-navbar)',
        },
    },
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect the problem is in the way I am defining my loaders but the order and the options provided seem correct. Please help me out.

Comment: did you find any solution I am stuck in the same condition

Comment: Any Solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't find a solution to this. However, the production build does automatically extract the output CSS into another file (extractCss: true).